# Two equivalent ways to define a class in a quotient vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

This is the theorem:

$$u + W = v + W \iff u-v \in W.$$

How can I prove it using two separate implications 
( $\Rightarrow$ and $ \ \Leftarrow$ ) ?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to tidy a little your presentation and to provide a title using adequate terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a third one in the middle:
$$u+W=v+W\iff u\in v+W\iff u-v\in W$$
The first $\implies$ holds because $0\in W$, hence $u\in u+W$. 
The second $\implies$ holds because then $u=v+w$ with some $w\in W$. 
Can you prove the other directions?